# Map view displaying two times when we call map view function in viewDidLayoutSubviews()?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, ios-autolayout, autolayout

I'm displaying map in my view. I'm using auto layout, that's why i called create map view function in viewDidLayoutSubviews(). viewDidLayoutSubviews() Called two times and map created two times, but initial map not removed from the view. When i call create map view function in viewDidLoad() it's creating only one time and it's not fit in to the view frame.

My code is...

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")

    loadMapView()//Call map view function

    let width = mapSubView.frame.size.width
    let x = mapSubView.frame.minX
    let y = mapSubView.frame.minY

    searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: x+10, y: y+10, width: width, height: 40)
    mapSubView.addSubview(searchBar)
    searchBar.delegate = self
    // hide cancel button
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    // set Default bar status.
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.default

    let y1 = searchBar.frame.maxY
    searchTableView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y1, width: width, height: searchTableView.frame.size.height)
    mapSubView.addSubview(searchTableView)

    searchTableView.delegate = self
    searchTableView.dataSource = self


}

//Create map view
func loadMapView() {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 19.3822559, longitude: 80.2194394, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: mapSubView.frame.size.width-2, height: mapSubView.frame.size.height-2), camera: camera)
    mapSubView.addSubview(mapView)
     print("map : \(mapSubView.frame.size.height)")
    print("map : \(mapView)")
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.3822559, longitude: 80.2194394)
    marker.title = ""
    marker.snippet = ""

    marker.map = mapView
}
```

How to fit map in my mapSubView?

[image]

Comment: You should layout the MapView where you set the screen's other layouts or create it in the viewDidLoad with the proper constraints. You should never call addSubView in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method because it's called multiple times (eg. when you rotate your device to landscape).

Comment: @ Péter Kovács thank you very much.. I will try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the code inside once var

```
var once = true
```

//

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")
    if once { 
        loadMapView()//Call map view function

        let width = mapSubView.frame.size.width
        let x = mapSubView.frame.minX
        let y = mapSubView.frame.minY

        searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: x+10, y: y+10, width: width, height: 40)
        mapSubView.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.delegate = self
        // hide cancel button
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        // set Default bar status.
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.default

        let y1 = searchBar.frame.maxY
        searchTableView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y1, width: width, height: searchTableView.frame.size.height)
        mapSubView.addSubview(searchTableView)

        searchTableView.delegate = self
        searchTableView.dataSource = self
        once = false
    } 
}
```

or use constraints in `viewDidLoad`

```
mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate( [

    mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapSubView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapSubView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapSubView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
    mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapSubView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),

])
```

Comment: Actually now map creating only one time but it not fit exactly in mapSubView frame.

Comment: mapSubView is pre-added in IB ? or you add it programmatically ? ,Also try constraints

Comment: Yes, when I add mapSubView programmatically it's working...Thank you

Comment: it will work anywhere but **viewDidLayoutSubviews** it not officially suitable for them , as before it's called multiple times and any code inside it should be wrapped in once var except if it's overrides a frame for a view or doing a job that doesn't make a duplicate or conflict